# Adding controller/action to URI using UriBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, uri

I am trying to create a Url after a  certain operation and this url should point to a different controller and actions. I also need to include some parameters so they provide the target controller with information needed. so lets say I have a controller called:

```
DoWorkController.cs
```

and an Action

```
public void Add(params...){..}
```

I am using UriBuilder in my homepage controller like this:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
builder.Port = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port;
//got stuck here        
Uri ret = builder.Uri;
return ret;
```

I want it to pull the controller name and action name and assign it to builder then add parameters, I am not sure how to do this. Suggestions??

**EDIT**

I solved the path-to-controller-to-action problem, I am still stuck on adding parameters to the url.

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
builder.Port = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port;
string path;
if (operation == 1)
    path = Url.Action("Add", "DoWork");
else if(operation ==2)
    path = Url.Action("Delete", "DoWork");
else
    throw new ArgumentException("Operation is neither Add or Delete");
if (path != null)
{
    builder.Path = path;
}
Uri ret = builder.Uri;
```

Comment: You can add parameters to the URL as follows: Url.Action("Add", "DoWork", new { parameterName1 = parameterValue1, parameterName2 = parameterValue2 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to your Url.Action in following way:

```
Url.Action("GetByList", "Listing", new { name = "John"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the home page controller, then you already know the controller name, no?

But to answer your question, the way to get the controller and action name is to get it from the `routeData`:

```
RouteData rd = ViewContext.RouteData;
var controllerName = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
var actionName = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
```